# Can I get some help with a verification problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to verify that $y = e^{-(1/2)x^2}$ for $\dfrac{y}{x}y'+y^2=0$.

I took the derivative of the first equation and found $y' = -xe^{-(1/2)x^2}$ which I then substituted $y$ back in and got $y' = -xy$. Doing algebra I got $\dfrac{y'}{x}+y = 0$, however I'm stuck on how to get another $y$ in there to make it $\dfrac
{y}{x}y'+y^2=0$.

Comment: Now that I see, you can simply multiply $y$ on both sides of equation (Right hand side is $0$).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply solve the differential equation:
$$\dfrac{y}{x}y'+y^2=0$$
$$y'+xy=0$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-xy$$
$$\int \dfrac{dy}{y}=-\int xdx $$
$$\ln y=-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+C$$
$$y=e^{\dfrac{-x^2}{2}+C}$$
This gives the family of solutions for this ODE, substituting $C=0$ in this gives the solution you needed to verify.

If you want to verify by differentiation:
$$y=e^{\dfrac{-x^2}{2}}$$
$$y'=-xe^{\dfrac{-x^2}{2}}$$
$$\dfrac{y}{x}y'=-e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=-e^{-x^2}=-y^2$$
$$\dfrac{y}{x}y'+y^2=0$$